# Rail and Fly arrival in Frankfurt: where to pick up luggage

Tags: luggage, airports, lufthansa

I have purchased a Rail and Fly ticket once,  after I already had bought the plane ticket. I ended up picking my luggage st the normal luggage belt,  and carrying it to the train station myself. However,  I saw signs saying I should pick them up st the Lufthansa Center at the train station.

I now have relatives flying in to Germany for the first time and want to make sure:

Is there a way to find out beforehand where the luggage has to be picked up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you book Rail&Fly, you always pick up your luggage at the terminals, where you arrive. Only if you have booked a connection with ExpressRail (https://www.lufthansa.com/de/en/Lufthansa-Express-Rail), you pick up your luggage at the ExpressRail Terminal at the train station. ExpressRail can be identified by having a specific train connection with a Lufthansa code (like LH36XX). Rail&Fly is a universal train ticket which is not tied to a specific train connection.